# Editing params nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Assume we have a rails params hash full of nested hashes and arrays. Is there a way to alter every string value (whether in nested hashes or arrays) which matches a certain criteria (e.g. regex) and still keep the output as a params hash (still containing nested hashes arrays?

I want to do some sort of string manipulation on some attributes **before** even assigning them to a model. Is there any better way to achieve this?

**[UPDATE]**
Let's say we want to select the strings that have an h in the beginning and replace it with a 'b'. so we have: 
before:

`{ a: "h343", b: { c: ["h2", "s21"] } }`

after:

`{ a: "b343", b: { c: ["b2", "s21"] } }`

For some reasons I can't do this with model callbacks and stuff, so it should have be done before assigning to the respective attributes.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: @SunnyK Just added an example.

Comment: I have no idea why someone would would change params which match a regexp rather than moving this logic back into the model (witch callback or just custom method)

Comment: @JoeHalfFace I'm currently facing this problem: I have users that submit Persian or Arabic numerals (well, to rails they're not numeral at all!) and it's going to be saved in an integer column in table. If a user submits '۱' instead of '1' in a field, rails just assigns a default 0 as the attribute's value instead of 1. So there's no callback for that since it isn't even saved.

Comment: I'm not quite sure. Bur rails should assign 0 when saving. So you can use `before_save` callback to change the values. Alternatively you can loop through params hash and output it's duplicate with change applied

Comment: Well, that's right. But '۱' is equivalent to '1' and since it's an attribute with integer type, rails couldn't make the assignment and instead, it just assign the default value of integer (0) to it. So, the original form ('۱') never gets saved hence I can't use before_save or any other callbacks.

Comment: I got it. Then I think you can also as possibility use the extension to ActiveModel and extend new (initialize) method of this given model. But if you want to go with params changing, for sure is the way, but honestly feels a little bit clumsy to me

Comment: @JoeHalfFace Interesting... could you further explain this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> still keep the output as a params hash (still containing nested hashes arrays

Sure.

You'll have to manipulate the `params` hash, which is done in the controller.

<s>Whilst I don't have lots of experience with this</s> I just spent a bunch of time testing -- you can use a blend of the [`ActionController::Parameters`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) class and then using `gsub!` -- like this:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_params, only: :create

   def create
      # Params are passed from the browser request
      @model = Model.new params_hash
   end

   private

   def params_hash
      params.require(:x).permit(:y).each do |k,v|
         v.gsub!(/[regex]/, 'string')
      end
   end
end
```

I tested this on one of our test apps, and it worked perfectly:

[image]

[image]

[image]

--

There are several important points.

Firstly, when you call a `strong_params` hash, `params.permit` *creates* a new hash out of the passed params. This means you can't just modify the passed params with `params[:description] =` etc. You have to do it to the permitted params.

Secondly, I could only get the `.each` block working with a bang-operator (`gsub!`), as this changes the value directly. I'd have to spend more time to work out how to do more elaborate changes.

--

**Update**

If you wanted to include nested hashes, you'd have to call another loop:

```
def params_hash
  params.require(:x).permit(:y).each do |k,v|
      if /_attributes/ ~= k
        k.each do |deep_k, deep_v|
           deep_v.gsub!(/[regex]/, 'string'
        end
      else
        v.gsub!(/[regex]/, 'string')
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think this solution would work in case that the permitted params includes nested arrays or hashes (e.g. if you're using accepts_nested_attributes_for).

Comment: yea, if we have this as permitted params: "{"name"=>"hello", "ch"=>{"a"=>"12", "b"=>"13"}}" then each method only selects "hello" and {"a"=>"12", "b"=>"13"} as values. But I want to alter the values inside of the nested hash as well.

Comment: Thanks! Although I think to support cases with several nested hashes, a recursive approach would be better

Comment: Yep but to get it working, I would definitely be using small steps like above

Answer (score 0):

In general you should not alter the original `params` hash. When you use strong parameters to whitelist the params you are actually creating a copy of the params - which can be modified if you **really need to**.

```
def whitelist_params
  params.require(:foo).permit(:bar, :baz)
end
```

But if mapping the input to a model is too complex or you don't want to do it on the model layer you should consider using a [service object](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services).

Comment: I'm ok with a copy of params, too. Though I don't want to whitelist or delete any keys or values from the has. I just want to modify some of the string values.

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't really answer the question, sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a hash like this:

```
hash = { "hello" => { "hello" => "hello", "world" => { "hello" => "world", "world" => { "hello" => "world" } } }, "world" => "hello" }
```

Then add a function that transforms the "ello" part of all keys and values into "i" (meaning that "hello" and "yellow" will become "hi" and "yiw")

```
def transform_hash(hash, &block)
  hash.inject({}){ |result, (key,value)|
    value = value.is_a?(Hash) ? transform_hash(value, &block) : value.gsub(/ello/, 'i')
    block.call(result, key.gsub(/ello/, 'i'), value)
    result
  }
end
```

Use the function like:

```
new_hash = transform_hash(hash) {|hash, key, value| hash[key] = value }
```

This will transform your hash and it's values regardless of the nesting level. However, the values should be strings (or another Hash) otherwise you'll get an error. to solve this problem just change the `value.is_a?(Hash)` conditional a bit.

**NOTE** that I strongly recommend you *NOT* to change the keys of the hash!